# How do you clear an Image from the DNN module cache

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have a DNN 7 custom module that allows the user to select a photo associated with their login.  I have it set up so the photo has a name that's always the same for each user (e.g. User1.jpg).

When the user updates their photo, I still see the old photo until they logout and then back in again.  I've confirmed that the image on disk is correct but DNN is going to its cache for the old photo.  How do I clear my module's cache during a post back from C#.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To clear the module cache, you can use the method DataCache.ClearModuleCache(TabId). Based on your requirement you can also use the methods Config.Touch() for complete app recycle. The namespace is Dotnetnuke.Common.Utilities.

Comment: I added        DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.DataCache.ClearModuleCache(this.TabId); but it's still not working.  If I add a guid to the image name to make the name unique it does work as expected but I'd rather not have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to update cache. create image url with last modified time stamp in querystring. so say for example your image is modified on 1st may 2013 you can build url that looks like:
`http(s)://domain/path/image.extension?modified=20130501`

as soon as your image modifies, your modified date has to be updated and the query string will change to that date. for example its last updated on 15th may
`http(s)://domain/path/image.extension?modified=20130515`

This way you don't need to update cache.

Since you are doing custom module, you can implement this easily.